# Merge array rows based on two columns and sum another column

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have this array:

```
array(
    array('id' => 1, 'price' => 20.00, 'stock' => 2, 'year' => 11 ),
    array('id' => 1, 'price' => 20.00, 'stock' => 3, 'year' => 12 ),
    array('id' => 1, 'price' => 20.00, 'stock' => 2, 'year' => 13 ),
    array('id' => 2, 'price' => 36.00, 'stock' => 11, 'year' => 13 ),
);
```

I need to sum the "stock" column when the `id` is the same (is the same article) and the years are 12 AND 13.

The result should be:

```
array(
    array('id' => 1, 'price' => 20.00, 'stock' => 2, 'year' => 11 ),
    array('id' => 1, 'price' => 20.00, 'stock' => 5, 'year' => 13 ),
    array('id' => 2, 'price' => 36.00, 'stock' => 11, 'year' => 13 ),
);
```

Notice the 'year' => 12 has been removed and the stock of that row has been added to the 13 row.

I can't do this without creating a big mess of spaguetti code with a bunch of bucles. Maybe there is a php function to this in a cleaner way?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: A PHP function that groups certain rows of a multidimensional array (specified by some arbitrary condition), sums a specific column and assumes that the non-grouped, non-summed columns have the same value (because otherwise the grouping would not make sense)? No. But SQL does that. Perhaps you should look there for the solution?

Comment: It's a good idea, but how can i group by year when its 12 or 13? not always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on solving this issue using PHP instead of your database, this will do the trick:

```php
function group_sum($array) 
{
    $return = array();

    foreach ($array as $v)
    {
        $key = $v['id'] . '_' . ($v['year'] == 12 ? 13 : $v['year']);

        if (array_key_exists($key, $return))
        {
            $return[$key]['stock'] += $v['stock'];

            if ($v['year'] > $return[$key]['year'])
                $return[$key]['year'] = $v['year'];
        }
        else
        {
            $return[$key] = $v;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try and reach upto here...Please anyone can push this code little...

```
$ary = array(
  array('id' => 1, 'price' => 20.00, 'stock' => 8, 'year' => 11 ),
  array('id' => 1, 'price' => 20.00, 'stock' => 3, 'year' => 12 ),
  array('id' => 1, 'price' => 20.00, 'stock' => 2, 'year' => 13 ),
  array('id' => 2, 'price' => 36.00, 'stock' => 11, 'year' => 13 ),
);

$ary2 = $ary;
$i=0;
foreach($ary as $row){

foreach($ary2 as $row2){
    if($row['id']==$row2['id'] && $row['year'] > $row2['year']){
        $ary[$i]['stock'] = $row['stock'] + $row2['stock'];
        unset($row);
    }   
}
//
$i++;
}
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($ary);
```